# Hibernate 5: Auto updated timestamp field for last modified

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity in Hibernate 5, which have creation and last modified timestamps. I want them to get auto update.

```
/**
 * Time of creation of entity
 */
@Column(name = "created_on", nullable = false)
private Timestamp createdOn;

/**
 * Time of last update
 */
@Column(name = "last_update", nullable = false)
private Timestamp lastUpdate;
```

I did it with Hibernate 4, using mapping xml file as follow :

```
    <property name="createdOn" type="java.sql.Timestamp" generated="insert" not-null="true">
        <column name="created_on" sql-type="timestamp" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
    </property>
    <property name="lastUpdate" type="java.sql.Timestamp" generated="always" not-null="true">
        <column name="last_update" sql-type="timestamp" default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
    </property>
```

But don't know how to do it in Hibernate 5 using annotations.

Answer (score 6):

**Method 1:**

You can use something like below:

```
@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
createdOn = new Date();
}

@PreUpdate
protected void onUpdate() {
 lastUpdate = new Date();
}
```

Note: JPA callbacks won't work if you are using `Session` API.

**Method 2:**

You can annotate `lastUpdate` field with `@Version` annotation. Apart from auto-populating the field it will also introduce optimistic locking for the entity. For the `createdOn` field, you can simply initialize it in the default constructor of the entity.

**Method 3:**

Use event listeners and update the relevant properties manually. You need to create a listener that extends `DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener` and override the `onSaveOrUpdate` method. Don't forget to register the event listener.

**Method 4:**
You can also use `@CreationTimestamp` and `@UpdateTimestamp` annotations for the `createdOn` and `lastUpdate` fields respectively.

Comment: Is PrePersist and PreUpdate are supported by Hibernate 5.2?

Comment: My entity is given by web client in form of json, which I deserialize into POJO. So I don't want to set creation and update time from client rather server should do that its own. But None of the methods working.

Comment: `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` are supported by Hibernate 5.2
If the value you get in JSON is different than the one that is currently in managed entity, then `@Version` will not update the annotated field.

Comment: What if value coming from client is null ?

Comment: Check method 4 in the edited answer. That could be more straightforward and simple to use. Check this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/topical/html/generated/GeneratedValues.html#_in_memory_generation) for details.

Answer (score 0):

worth to use setter method

```
public void setLastUpdate ( TimeStamp lastu ) {
   this.lastUpdate = lastu == null ? 0 : new Date);
}
```