# how to fix this issue org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 4

Tags: spring, hibernate

This is my code in Dao 
        `session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Router.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("router_id", router_id));

        Router router = (Router) criteria.uniqueResult();

        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        return router;`

In Hibernate getting like this
    `{"org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 4"}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can update a timestamp like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969919/hibernate-5-auto-updated-timestamp-field-for-last-modified) or if you already have a field with the timestamp, you need to modify your query.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23866709/org-hibernate-nonuniqueresultexception-query-did-not-return-a-unique-result-2)

Answer (score 1):

According to official hibernate doc,

> Thrown when the application calls Query.uniqueResult() and the query returned more than one result.

In your case, 4 results are returned. Make sure your query only returns one result.

Comment: Yes, i`m getting multiple results. But i need only last updated result.

Comment: How can i get last updated result? Thanks in advance

Comment: use setMaxResults to get 1 result. @BMAM

Comment: @BMAM there are multiple ways to get last updated result like get the first result by the last updated time in your table (assuming you have one, it is pretty easy to do with HQL or criteria). you can create a new thread to get help on this question.